# Trouble simulating a Pierce crystal oscillator circuit

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I am trying to simulate a Pierce crystal oscillator on programs such as Falstad and LTspice.  I have tried around eight different designs now and they seem unable to produce a sine wave in either simulator despite my knowledge that these designs do in fact work.

[Here is the circut in question](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORI5ISJdApgLRhgBQASiOuteqlQ8+PIpCgSxNCeJgJ2AY2HVkyHOFwo1EsC1JRo+dFjBZyCBOjAI86mHA4B3ZVvWq32yOyJh0Gj+qmbqjUEJAAOgDOmKg4ZuQJieSoLGxRqNhEWAJkZEQ+kMgIUfaQYVG6rMjpmXHGkKRsWKjNRCWwZVDtcPhEOBXQCKYI2USN6IV4WAh6JV2RONBE7ABW-iA+6rzUmyh+zNSlvvLO264uYrLsAOYXyH5n+UJXAE7ru0EbVDrwv+zOnzQoU0uy8t0+fWB6iIqFkUHYABsXAIhGd3DIOnAktikgYyr9IGNUDZILFBHZ2AB7HjgSQNfRSUpY3A2fASB4oKkoWniMS0RmYhosvBICB+ZCcoA) which I simulated in Falstad with the same exact component values and setup that produced a fairly clean sine wave in [this tutorial](https://community.element14.com/challenges-projects/project14/makingtime/b/blog/posts/a-crystal-clock-with-1-transistor---the-pierce-oscillator). Because I know that this circuit works in real life, and I've been able to design working LC circuits (like Clapp and Colpitts) using these same exact simulators.  Is it simply that both programs fail to accurately simulate crystals?

While these programs are good, I know that everything has its limits, and I'm certain that this very widely used and well-documented crystal oscillator which has been used over and over is to blame. Even if this tutorial happens to be wrong, I've done about a dozen which produced the same result. No sine wave.

Perhaps they are too idealistic? I've had prior issues with Falstad messing up a circuit using an H-bridge because the transistor would turn on for picoamps of current, and while I know you can adjust the shutoff voltage, it just goes to show how sensitive they are to certain conditions.

The best case scenario here is that I've done something completely wrong and easily identifiable which can be rectified by you guys in the comments, rather than me physically having to buy some of these components and solder them together onto a perfboard and connect them up to an oscilloscope only to then find my mistake.

Comment: You show a 10M resistor in your simulation. In Spice, 10M means 10 milliohms (perhaps this is different in Falstad). If you want a 10Meg resistor, you need to specify the value as **10meg** as per Spice syntax. You also may need to provide a kick-start to make this oscillate. Applying a snappy pulse once in series with the bias resistor will generally get things oscillating.

Comment: Tried a similar circuit in LTSpice, with a more complex 100uH choke that included series resistance and parallel capacitance to simulate self-resonant-frequency. Also included stray capacitance. And started the 9V supply at 0V. Still took around 20 milliseconds for amplitude to build...crystals take **a long time** to build amplitude, especially when LTspice doesn't factor in noise. Perhaps you're not waiting long enough.

Comment: @qrk The weirdest thing just happened. I remembered capital M meaning megaohms in falstad, but I went to check just in case. I switched the capital M to a lowercase m (which would then be miliohms if my memory served correct) and suddenly a waveform appeared! Not a good clean sine wave like the one in the tutorial, so i assume it was coincidental, but weird nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to simulate a pierce crystal oscillator on programs such as
> falstad and LTSpice, however I have tried around 8 different designs
> now and they seem unable to produce a sine wave in either, despite my
> knowledge that these designs DO in fact work.*

Pierce oscillators produce square waves and **NOT** sine waves: -

[image]

Image from [Wikipedia - pierce oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator): -

> **Virtually all digital IC clock oscillators are of Pierce type, as the
> circuit can be implemented using a minimum of components: a single
> digital inverter, one resistor, two capacitors, and the quartz
> crystal, which acts as a highly selective filter element.**

As with any crystal oscillator, if you want a decent sinewave, you need to add circuitry that keeps the output voltage amplitude controlled to well-within the power rails thus preventing distortion.

Comment: That's a bit misleading - Square waves are not unique to Pierce oscillators - any oscillator will tend to do that if there is a lot of excess gain and no other amplitude control mechanism except limiting.

Comment: For producing a sinewave-like output you must reduce the gain of the CMOS device (add negative feedback). Then, soft-limiting can be made exploiting the non-linear transfer characteristic of the inverter. More than that, it is recommended to use an ohmic resistor Rx between X1 and R1 (right side) in order to realize a third-order lowpass Rx-C2-L1-C1 (L1 is provided by the crystal X1).